# IDE для C++ с использованием QT

Tags: ide, qt, c++

Какую IDE лучше использовать под разработку на C++ с использованием QT и нормальным отладчиком?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Лучше эти:

1. Qt Creator
2. MSVS с Qt-addin

Comment: а msvs какую версию лутше? а то я пробовал qt+msvs 2003 и 2005, установилось все с глюками.

Comment: я использую MSVS2010 + vs-add-in-1.1.11

Comment: >> а msvs какую версию лутше? а то я пробовал qt+msvs 2003 и 2005, установилось все с глюками.

Ты еще более древние версии MSVS попробуй.